# PHP selecting duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table, duplicates

I have the following mysql table :

```
id   store_t  item  qty
1      M5      xx    2
2      M5      xy    4
3      M8      ze    10
4      M5      zz    1
```

I want the table output to be like this :

```
M5
xx   2
xy   4
zz   1

M8
ze   10
```

What i am looking for is to find a way to group and select the duplicate `store_t` and output its `item` and `qty` without repeating `store_t`.

I've tried using `GROUP BY store_t` inside mysql statement it works to group the Duplicates of store_t but only showing one record of item and qty.

Here is my code :

```
$query = "SELECT * from transfer_check GROUP BY store_t";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

//Table Created for each Store

echo "<table width=80% align=center border=2 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0>";
echo "<tr><td align=center colspan=2>".$row['store_t']."</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td align=center bgcolor=white><b>Item No.</b></td><td align=center 
bgcolor=lightgreen><b>QTY Transferred</b></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td align=center><b>".strtoupper($row['item_no'])."</b></td><td align=center>  <b>".$row['qty']."</b></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";


//End of i loop
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ordering the results by `store_t` and then looping through them?

Something like:

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * from transfer_check ORDER BY store_t";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    ?><table><?php
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
    ?><tr><?php
       if ( !isset($curStore) || $curStore != $row['store_t'] ) {              
           $curStore = $row['store_t'];
           echo "<td colspan='2'>$curStore</td></tr><tr>";
       }
       echo "<td>{$row['item']}</td><td>{$row['qty']}</td>";
       ?></tr>
   }?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/) to group the values from the sql and then parse the results in PHP loop.

First of all here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03e35/6/0) with the required result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  store_t, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT item ORDER BY item) as items_list,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT qty ORDER BY qty) as qty
FROM myTable 
  GROUP BY store_t
```

The result will be:

```
STORE_T ITEMS_LIST  QTY
M5      xx,xy,zz    1,2,4
M8      ze          10
```

Now we need to loop trough this result to create the structure you wanted, for every row (store_t) we will get values of `qty` and `item`. We will split it into array (for display purpose only).

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());

while ($record = mssql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $items_array = explode(",",$record['items_list']);
      $qty_array = explode(",",$record['qty']);
      echo $record['store_t'] . ": <br/>";
      for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($items_array); $i++) {
          echo "Item:" . $items_array[$i] . " QTY: " . $qty_array[$i]; 
      }
}
```

The output will be:

```
M5
Item: xx QTY: 1
Item: xy QTY: 2
```

etc...